# Different date format in UNIX and Linux server

Tags: linux, unix, format

I am migrating all my script from UNIX server to Linux server, but both the server have different date format.

How I can make both format same ?

UNIX:
 bash-3.2$ date
 Tuesday, 25 October 2016 15:57:04 BST

LINUX:
 [ess@gmessd04 ~]$ date
 Tue 25 Oct 16:01:20 BST 2016

Unix server version : SunOS 5.10

Linux server version : Linux 3.10

Thanks,
Shadab Hussain

Answer (score 1):

You could use the parameter of the date command to get the same result on linux you have on unix.

```
$date "+%A, %d %B %k:%M:%S %Z"
```

For more info about the date modifier see manpage of date command:

```
$man date
```

If you need like to change the output of date without typing the parameter all the time, you could set it as alias:

```
$alias date='date "+%A, %d %B %k:%M:%S %Z"'
```

Comment: Okay Thanks for the above command. using above command I can change the date format but can we change it server level itself ? I mean If I will run data command on both server then it should give same output. so I don't have to use any conversion command itself ?

Comment: You could include the alias in `.bashrc` then it will override the date command with the alias in every console you start.